# Split view into 2 views for google cardboard for iOS

Tags: ios, view, split, panoramas

I'm using https://bitbucket.org/javieralonso/japanoview to create 360 degree panoramic views for an iOS app. What I want to do now is split the view into 2 identical views and use one input for both of them and be able to use it inside google cardboard. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once used this as inspiration to do the same thing. https://github.com/nicklockwood/ReflectionView
Set reflection to dynamic. View is mirrored but you can fix if by removing values smaller than zero.
Also translate method to make it next to each other. Remove gradient drawing and you are set to go :)

Comment: First of all thank you for sharing that code with me. I've been able to create a rough version of what I'm looking for with that.

What I'm confused about is when you say,

"View is mirrored but you can fix if by removing values smaller than zero. Also translate method to make it next to each other. Remove gradient drawing and you are set to go". 

Which variables and methods in specific are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard add view you want to duplicate on left half of screen and set its Class to ReflectionView.
Reflection view implementation changes will look like this:

```
- (void)update {
    //update instances
    CAReplicatorLayer *layer = (CAReplicatorLayer *)self.layer;
    layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    layer.instanceCount = 2;
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, layer.bounds.size.width + _reflectionGap, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    layer.instanceTransform = transform;
    layer.instanceAlphaOffset = 1.0f;
}

- (void)setUp {
    //set default properties
    _reflectionGap = 0.0f;
    _dynamic = YES;
    //update reflection
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Comment: I have used your code but only 1 of the views is being shown, and the reflected view is not shown. I'm trying to have 2 views being shown side by side.

Comment: Disable clip subviews on that view

Comment: I did but it's still not showing. I don't know which value to change. I've played around with changing values for the translate and transform methods but I'm still not able to get what I want.

Comment: Code I sent was tested, no changes to translate method are required. Try to put some subviews inside to see whether they will be displayed correctly.

Comment: Finally got it working! My mistake was that I wasn't using the exact update method you had made. Thanks for the help!